# bada Programming - Scroll panel does not display all editFields

Tags: c++, bada

The tab I'm working on has 12 editfields, the scrollpanel does not display all of it, the last 2 editfields gets chopped/cut off. They are only displayed when I click into them and put in some input. May I know how to solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Scrollpanel.add these edit boxes to scrollpanel and add scrollpanel to Form.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding! Yes, I used scrollpanel and changed the height of the scrollpanel and it displays everything now. :)